# How to call an internal javascript function from url?

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, excel

I'm collecting some data from a series of similar webpages and store them in excel sheet. I'm using the opener class in urllib2 within python for this work.

The problem is that in one group of these pages, you need too click on a hyperlink so that the needed data appear.

Is there any way that I could fake the click on this hyperlink and include it in the address that I send within my python code?

This is the href tag of the link:

```
<a href="#" onClick="refresh_reg_table();refresh_reg_list(); return false;">
```

And here are the functions called in onClick:

```
function refresh_reg_table(order){
  Ajax.Responders.register({
    onCreate: function() {
      $('ajax_spinner2').show();
    },
    onComplete: function() {
      $('ajax_spinner2').hide();
    }
  });

  new Ajax.Updater('table_registrations', 'ajax/get_table_registrations.php', { 
    method: 'get',
    parameters: {
      table: 'registrations',
      idevent : 143593,
      sorted : order},
    evalScripts: true,
  });
}

function refresh_reg_list(){
  Ajax.Responders.register({
   onCreate: function() {
     $('ajax_spinner2').show();
   },
   onComplete: function() {
     $('ajax_spinner2').hide();
   }
  });

  new Ajax.Updater('reg_list', 'ajax/get_list_registrations.php', { 
    method: 'get',
    parameters: {
      type: 'table_name_reg',
      idevent : 143593
    },
    evalScripts: true,
  });  
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use some CLI WebKit for browser like behaviour. (Not sure on urlib capabilities in that field.)

Answer (score 0):

All you can do through the address bar is using the `javascript:` prefix and it would run all your JavaScript code after that `javascript:` prefix.

you also better change the your hyperlink like:

```
<a href="javascript:refresh_reg_table();refresh_reg_list();">...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `javascript:yourFunction()` to start the page's function - i dont think there's any other way around it

Comment: My question might have been unclear and so I just edited it. Opener does not accept the second command with Javascript code. I guess it doesn't work the same way as address bar in browsers. How can I include `javascript:function()` in the page address that I'm calling?

Comment: I dont think theres you can do that - but you can include in that page's body tag <body onload="startUpFunction()"> once you access it - instead..